# Where do I place "forever" in this sentence? "I relieve you of this burden."

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

1. "I **forever** relieve you of this burden."
2. "I relieve you **forever** of this burden."
3. "I relieve you of this burden **forever**."

Maybe you think you have a better place for "forever" in this sentence?

Comment: How much emphasis do you want on the "I" and "forever", compared to "the burden"?

Comment: The first one is likely the most natural and depicts strong emotions. The second one is uncommon. The third one is again an okay choice I would say.